# Unable to get ArcGIS Pro utility network, Trace Tool output in PyCharm

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pycharm, trace, utility-network

I am trying to run Trace Tool in PyCharm using ArcPy and get the traced features in PyCharm but after running the Trace tool in PyCharm I am not getting the traced features details.
I am running this set of code

```py
import arcpy
gdb = "some_gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
fds = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Feature")
results = arcpy.un.Trace()
for i in results:
   print(i)
```

Instead of traced features I am getting output like this:

D:\UNM\GDB\CPA_Electric_12Apr23_DeltaUpdated_3x.gdb\Trace_Results_Aggregated_Points
D:\UNM\GDB\CPA_Electric_12Apr23_DeltaUpdated_3x.gdb\Trace_Results_Aggregated_Lines
D:\UNM\GDB\CPA_Electric_12Apr23_DeltaUpdated_3x.gdb\Trace_Results_Aggregated_Polygons